# NSLayoutManager with an NSTextContainer per paragraph

Tags: ios, ios7, textkit

How do I make an NSLayoutManager that assigns each paragraph in its text to a different NSTextContainer?

This would be similar to the multiple page/column usage that is common in TextKit, but each page corresponds to a different paragraph of variable length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to subclass NSTextContainer and override

`- (CGRect)lineFragmentRectForProposedRect:(CGRect)proposedRect atIndex:(NSUInteger)characterIndex writingDirection:(NSWritingDirection)baseWritingDirection remainingRect:(CGRect *)remainingRect`

In your custom method, you'd inspect the attributes at `characterIndex` and see if they matched the paragraph that text container is assigned to. If they are, just return `super`'s implementation of the method, otherwise return `CGRectZero` to signify that the proposed rect is invalid for this text container. This does mean you'll have to track paragraph attributes and the text containers they correlate to (and vice versa).

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'm going to try this out when I get a chance and get back to you.

Comment: developer link is dead

Comment: I think this is the link you were talking about https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html (toward the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is inserting page break control character (ASCII code: 12) at the end of each paragraph.